# RestKit - mapping nested json into model class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, restkit, geojson

I have json which I want to mapp to a model class

```
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
 {
   "geometry": {
     "coordinates": [100.0, 0.0, 129, 1356044399]
   },
   "properties": {
    "name": "My first name",
    "description": "Popular place"
   }
 },
 {
   "geometry": {
     "coordinates": [100.0, 1.0, 127, 1356045399]
   },
   "properties": {
    "name": "My second TIP",
    "description": "Even more popular place"
   }
 }
 ]
}
```

I want to put this into a model class which is something like this:

```
@property longitude (taken from coordinates index 0)
@property latitude (taken from coordinates index 1)
@property name
@property description
```

Comment: What is the question that you are asking? Please try to be specific about what you've tried and any errors / problems that you're encountering. Looking at your question I'm not clear what it is you need me to say.

Comment: I am using Restkit and want to mapp this structure into a model class with the properties. I am not able to do this, because my model gets nil with every method I tried. I have tried to solve this problem using mapping like [mapping mapKeyPath:@"properties[name]" toAttribute:@"name"]; but is gives me nothing back...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the solution I came up with was the following:

Two models:

```
@interface WTFeaturesModel
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *type;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *features;

@interface WTFeatureModel
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *properties;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *geometry;
```

Mapping for models:

```
[featureMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"properties", @"geometry"]];

[featuresMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"type"]];
[featuresMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"features" toKeyPath:@"features" withMapping:featureMapping]];
```

And after I have created those models I have to map the data over to the other model with correct attributes. Anyway, this made the mapping to work...